# Primitive Setters and NSManagedObjectContext Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When using primitive setters (e.g. `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`)to change values of `NSManagedObjects` (or their subclasses), will these changes be included in the userInfo of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notifications, or the objects be listed in the updatedObjects of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notifications?

Subsequently, will values set by primitives be saved to disk? (assuming use of a sqlite persistent store)

I haven't been able to find any specific information on this, and I'd rather not make assumptions from my limited testing, or at least not without (attempting) a deeper understanding of it. Thanks!

Comment: What are the results of your testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some further testing with a small sample project to minimize other factors, and here are my findings:

Saving is dependent on `willChangeValue:forKey:` notifications. As long as the `NSManagedObject` is KVC compliant for that key, this call will set the object's `hasChanges` flag to `YES`. When this happens, an object will be included in the next `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification. The `NSManagedObject` itself knows exactly which values have changed though, regardless of what keys KVO notifications were posted for.

> E.g. even if key A is changed via the primitive setter, and a notification is posted for key B's change, the object will notice the change for key A.

Similarly, `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` will only save an object whose `hasChanges` is `YES` but again, the object knows of all changed values regardless of the notifications posted, and all changes will be saved to disk.

I was surprised that `didChangeValue:forKey:` does not have any effect on saving behaviour. It is key to undo management though, which requires the standard wrapping of KVO calls around the primitive setter to function:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"key"];
[self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"key"];`
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the primitive value you should make sure the notifications are fired by including the appropriate calls manually. From apple sample code "DateSectionTitles":

```
// getter
[self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
[self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

// setter
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
[self setPrimitiveTimeStamp:newDate];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

The `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotication` notification will be fired if you set the primitive value.

As for the notification, according to the docs:

> The userInfo dictionary contains the following keys: NSInsertedObjectsKey, NSUpdatedObjectsKey, and NSDeletedObjectsKey.